# Why is the Vyper Bytecode smaller? What is it giving up?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, vyper

I have two contracts that are essentially the same, but one is in vyper:

```py
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
# @version ^0.3.3

my_var: public(uint256)

@external
def update_var(my_new_var: uint256):
    self.my_var = my_new_var
```

And one is in solidity:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract BasicSolContract {
    uint256 public myVar;

    function updateVar(uint256 myNewVar) external {
        myVar = myNewVar;
    }
}
```

However, they have drastically different bytecodes, and drastically different gas costs:

### Vyper ByteCode:

```
0x61004f61001863000000003961004f6000016300000000f3600436101561000d57610044565b60003560e01c3461004a57632c45d69a811861002b57600435600055005b63df35f89181186100425760005460405260206040f35b505b60006000fd5b600080fd
```

gas: ~70,202

### Solidity ByteCode:

```
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060325760003560e01c806314242c65146037578063c6b91540146049575b600080fd5b604760423660046063565b600055565b005b605160005481565b60405190815260200160405180910390f35b600060208284031215607457600080fd5b503591905056fea2646970667358221220c53bbcf5b9f000192bb05876522bb77484ccaea5cf508f2586ed1eeb8d14456a64736f6c63430008070033
```

gas: ~91,623

So my question(s) is(are):

What is vyper "giving up" to have smaller bytecode and use less gas?

What is solidity doing "extra" to have a larger bytecode and use more gas?

## More clarifications

To compile these, I used brownie (and doubled checked the solidity in remix)

- Compiler Version: 0.8.7
- Optimizer Enabled
- 200 Runs

> EDIT
> Using in-line assembly doesn't help for solidity here. You'd just change the `updateVar` function as such:
>
> ```js
>    function updateVar(uint256 myNewVar) external {
>        assembly {
>            sstore(0, myNewVar)
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> Which actually makes the contract somehow perform worse gas-wise.

Comment: Is the solidity code optimized?

Comment: The optimizer is enabled with 200 runs

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with vyper not using a free memory pointer, which allows it to be much more concise with its opcodes. The tradeoff is that dynamic arrays are not possible. So solidity went with flexibility while vyper has gone for gas optimization.